# Text not used again if it used once in Random Method

Tags: android, random, textview

I am using random text from the string.xml to my textview through Random method. Now I don't want to use the text again if it has been used once. Help will be appreciated.

I put the text in string.xml

```
<string name="one">1</string>
<string name="two">2</string>
<string name="three">3</string>
<string name="four">4</string>
<string name="five">5</string>
<string name="six">6</string>
<string name="seven">7</string>
<string name="eight">8</string>
<string name="nine">9</string>
<string name="ten">10</string>

<string name="one_explaination">This is number one</string>
<string name="two_explaination">This is number two</string>
<string name="three_explaination">This is number three</string>
<string name="four_explaination">This is number four</string>
<string name="five_explaination">This is number five</string>
<string name="six_explaination">This is number six</string>
<string name="seven_explaination">This is number seven</string>
<string name="eight_explaination">This is number eight</string>
<string name="nine_explaination">This is number nine</string>
<string name="ten_explaination">This is number ten</string>
```

My code in MainActivity:

```
Random number,number_explaination;
int [] array_number,array_number_explaination;
int textview_number,textview_number_explaination;
TextView textView1,textView2;

number = new Random();
array_number = new int[] {R.string.one,R.string.two,R.string.three,R.string.four,R.string.five,R.string.six,R.string.seven,
        R.string.eight,R.string.nine,R.string.ten};

array_number_explaination = new int[] {R.string.one_explaination,R.string.two_explaination,R.string.three_explaination,
        R.string.four_explaination,R.string.five_explaination,R.string.six_explaination,R.string.seven_explaination,
        R.string.eight_explaination,R.string.nine_explaination,R.string.ten_explaination};  

textview_number = number.nextInt(array_number.length - 1);
textView1.setText(getResources().getString(array_number[textview_number]));
textView2.setText(getResources().getString(array_number_explaination[textview_number]));
```

Comment: what problem you are getting?

Comment: I don't have any Idea how to do this...I want the text once to show after that the text should not show again...Means If I got 4 in my textview that next time it not be show again...

Comment: First, change `textview_number = number.nextInt(array_number.length - 1);` to `textview_number = number.nextInt(array_number_explaination.length - 1);` and you already showing random text in TextView then what problem u are getting?

Comment: @MikeM. How can I remove them

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I am getting the text randomly but if i get it once then it not show again to me on button click

Answer (score 0):

```
LinkedList<Integer>  number=new LinkedList<Integer>();
LinkedList<Integer>  number_exp=new LinkedList<Integer>();
//add data
int randomIndex=(int) (Math.random()*(strs.size()-1));
textview1.setText(number.get(randomIndex));
textview2.setText(number_exp.get(randomIndex));
number.remove(randomIndex);
number_exp.remove(randomIndex);
```

Comment: Could u please explain how can i add my string data here in the code.

Comment: I read your code again,use LinkedList<Integer> would be better.The method `LinkedList.add(Integer i)` would OK

Comment: I tried it...but it doesn't solve my problem....First I want Two texts randomly on two textview in one time...means this one "R.string.nine" and this "R.string.nine_explaination" and both remove from the list if it used once

Comment: int randomIndex=(int) (Math.random()*(strs.size()-1)); .....what to do with this "strs" in this code